# javascript how to express many-digit exponentials to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, decimal, exponential

I have a javascript program which spits out large arrays of numbers of the form '3.173538947635389377E+98', in the console, and have tried without luck to reduce them to something like '3.17E+98' for ease of comparison.

I Stringified the number, calculated the period and E locations, cut and diced until I had it of the string form '317.35E+96', with 96 as a multiple of 3.
Then when I re-expressed as a number using Number(), it reverted to '3.173538947635389377E+98'.
I could have left it as a string, but then would have to reconvert to Number later on.
Is there a simple way of reducing the complexity? It is nearly impossible to inspect and see similar numbers etc, when the strings are so long.  I guess the js people have their reasons, but am at my wits end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) with `engineering` notation:

```js
const display = (n) => new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
  notation: 'engineering',
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}).format(n);

console.log(display(3.173538947635389377E+98));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toFixed()` method to express many-digit exponentials to two decimal places.

For example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var num = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950;

var result = num.toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

// result will be 3.14

Comment: True, but the number you used is not an exponential, just a lot of decimals. toFixed() does not work with exponentials.